# WebSphere Liberty Code Dump Generated while running application with java instrumentation agent

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty, javaagents

Java Agent is not instrumenting methods starting with package `"com.ibm.ws"`.

But still getting javacore when server compiling below method:

```
2XHREGISTER      CR2: 0000000000000000
1XHEXCPMODULE  Compiling method: com/ibm/ws/security/jaspi/JaspiServletFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V
NULL
```

But when we exclude these methods using `-Xjit:exclude={...}` then not getting javacore as given in example below-

> 1CICMDLINE
>   /opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/jre_8.0.5040.20190923_1526/jre/bin/java
>   -javaagent:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/bin/tools/ws-javaagent.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x **-Xjit:exclude={com/ibm/ws/*}** -javaagent:/home/cavisson/netdiagnostics/lib/ndmain.jar=time,ndAgentJar=/home/cavisson/netdiagnostics/lib/ndagent-with-dep.jar,ndHome=/home/cavisson/netdiagnostics,logInstrCode=1
>   -Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=com.cavisson.ndutils -jar /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/bin/tools/ws-server.jar defaultServer

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a probably Java/JIT bug, not anything you did wrong or something that you could fix with configuration or setup. You could try a more recent Java version, in case this problem has been found and fixed already.
Otherwise, you should open a bug or PMR against IBM Java, so development can gather the necessary information to work the issue.